# Vagrant Monasca VM mounting failed with the error: No such device. Works with sudo

Tags: vagrant, openstack, devstack

I am trying to create DevStack + Monasca setup on a Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bits) host running on a VirtualMachine.
Using the setup instructions given here: https://github.com/openstack/monasca-vagrant

This is a 2 VM setup - devstack & monasca running on two different VMs.
vagrant is used to setup and provision the whole thing. It first brings
up Devstack VM. During this process mounting shared folders give the output + error:

```
stack@stack-vm:~/monasca-vagrant$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'devstack' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'mini-mon' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> devstack: Checking if box 'monasca/devstack' is up to date...
==> devstack: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> devstack: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> devstack: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    devstack: Adapter 1: nat
    devstack: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> devstack: Forwarding ports...
    devstack: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> devstack: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> devstack: Booting VM...
==> devstack: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    devstack: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    devstack: SSH username: vagrant
    devstack: SSH auth method: private key
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    devstack: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> devstack: Machine booted and ready!
==> devstack: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> devstack: Setting hostname...
==> devstack: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> devstack: Mounting shared folders...
    devstack: /vagrant => /home/stack/monasca-vagrant
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attemped was:

set -e
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the command was:

: No such device
```

However, if I ssh into the DevStack VM and use sudo with mount command then the command works fine. Also, I am able to see the contents of shared folder in the guest.
 So it seems, 'sudo' is required afterall for mounting the share. However, I am not able to find a way to do it through vagrant.
I tried to select 'auto-mount' from Virtualbox settings but they are also not editable.
Plus I made sure guest additions is installed on the Guest.

Would require and appreciate any help in successfully mounting the folders.

Thanks,
-Arun

Comment: install [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest)

Comment: I thought this plugin is required if the guestAdditions has a version mismatch. This plugin should auto-upgrade guestAdditions to correct version. However, as I am able to mount the folders successfully from within the guest, I didn't install this plugin. Is there something else to this plugin which I may no be aware of.

Comment: The plugin first install the guest-addition if its not present (and I have suspicion this is your case here) and if installed it looked at the version to keep guest and host in sync